# Как узнать значение ключа, лежащего во вложенности из объектов и массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив, содержащий какое-то количество объектов, каждый объект представляет из себя глубокую вложенность состоящую как из объектов, так и из массивов. Если хотя бы одно свойство Value равно примитивному значению, вернуть true.